# MySQL: required indexes for multi-column ordering

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Having a 10+ million table with three columns: `one`, `two`, `three` and SQL query like `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY one, two, three LIMIT 1` - do I really need to create a multi-column index using all three columns?

I know for sure that if `one` and `two` matches, there would be max 10 rows with distinct `three`.

Is it enough for fast SELECTs? -

`CREATE INDEX MY_INDEX ON table (one, two);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `INDEX(one, two, three)`, the query will go straight down the BTree to the one (`LIMIT 1`) desired row.

With `INDEX(one, two)`, the query will go straight down the BTree to the first such row, then scan forward the up-to-10 rows, save them to a tmp table, sort them (`ORDER BY` includes `three`) (probably done in memory), and deliver the first one.  Although this sounds more complex it will not (in this example) be much slower.

It will not be a "table scan" ("ALL"), but perhaps a "range" scan.  Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see.

If `three` is a bulky string, then the 3-col index will be bulkier; this has some impact on disk space and performance.

If you need only `(one, two)` for some other queries, then *either* index works reasonably well (barring the "bulky" comment).

If you do `SELECT one, two, three FROM ...`, the 3-part index will be better because it will be "covering".  `SELECT *` won't have such a bonus.

Bottom line:  Either index is "OK", many other factors factor in, making it hard to say for sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You might think MySQL is clever enough to only read at most the first 10 rows using the index and then sort these. Unfortunately, it isn't (because the optimizer doesn't regard the `limit` at this point). You can verify that by using `explain select ...`, it will show that MySQL will do a full table scan (`"ALL"`).

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) describes conditions to be able to use an index to optimize `order by`:

> The index can also be used even if the ORDER BY does not match the index exactly, as long as all unused portions of the index and all extra ORDER BY columns are constants in the WHERE clause.

Your third column does not satisfy this. So this query will not use this index (which does not mean that it might not be usefull for something else).

Since MySQL 5.6, there is however the so-called [filesort priority queue optimization](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/filesort-with-small-limit-optimization/) to accommodate the `limit`: while MySQL will still read the whole table, it will not sort the whole table (which would be a time consuming process), but will stop when it knows what the first row will be, which makes your query acceptable fast.

But you can rewrite your query to do exactly what you are thinking of:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (select * from table ORDER BY one, two LIMIT 10) sub
order by one, two, three limit 1;
```

This will read the first 10 rows using that index, and then just sort these. It will of course only work correctly if you are absolutely sure you will only have at most 10 rows.

A more general way to optimize your query independently from knowing the maximum number of possible rows would be e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table
where one = (select min(one) from table)
order by one, two, three limit 1;
```

This will use the index to reduce the number of rows that have to be read and filesorted by looking up the lowest value for `one` first (using the index) and only considering these rows. You can similarly include a condition for `two`.

Or you can simply can use all three columns in your index (although depending on the size of your third column, it can make sense to not do this). These kind of optimizations tend to catch up at one point. If you e.g. use the first method, and in 2 year there will be 11 rows possible, you (or your successor) will have to remember that you have this implied condition in your code.

Comment: I dispute the claim of "table scan".